# How can a superclass trigger an action in a subclass in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, superclass

So I have a tab-bar controller where each tab is a UITableView that extends from a superclass that I created.  This superclass (obviously) extends UITableViewController.

Each UITableViewController represents a tabbed view and has its own model that pulls data that is specific to each TableView, so I need to separate these methods and variables from the superclass.

However, I have implemented "pull-to-refresh" in my superclass and would like to refresh the data that is held by the subclass from the update method that is called when pulling-to-refresh.

Do I basically have to cut my losses and implement pull-to-refresh individually within every UITableViewController in my tabbar, or is there a way of getting the update command to call a method inherent (but implemented differently) within each UITableViewController in my tabbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your common superclass, create a method

```
-(void)onRefresh {
}
```

that does nothing. Call this method when you need to trigger an action in a subclass.

In each of your subclasses, implement a method with the same signature. These methods would be called when superclass calls

```
[self onRefresh];
```

Comment: Oh, fascinating.  I had no clue objective-c had this ability... and shame on me for not attempting this first.

Comment: while I browsed for something like an `@override` property as you might know from java, i stumbled upon an article in the developer docu: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MethodOverriding.html